Controlling for pupil light reflex when analyzing pupil size time course?
I used eye tracking to examine how participants from two different populations (A and B) react to an image.
Participants in population A exhibit larger pupil sizes over time, but they also have a much smaller pupil light reflex (a quick literature search confirms this finding).

If I control for pupil light reflex, participants from population B show larger pupil sizes.

My question is, does it make sense to control the pupil light reflex? Is it OK to do so in pupillometry research? I searched the literature on this topic but could not find an answer.

I have no idea, but this must be the most interesting question in years!

What is the rationale for this subtraction method (taking the lowest value)? Has this been used before?
To get dynamic range for each participant you can do this following from this paper (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8782349):
Take 2.5th and 97.5th percentile of the distribution of individual baseline-corrected minimum and maximum values as individual dynamic range and apply the correction factor.

Every participant saw the same images and sequence of events. I think if you take the dynamic pupil range and process as normal it should be fine and this will control for the fact that one group shows smaller pupil size in general.

What adjustment did you make to the pupil time course to get figure B? It does not seem standard and this could be causing your effects to flip.
What was your baseline here? How long and what was the stimulus?
If the baseline here also induces PLR, then if one group exhibits smaller PS during the baseline this could bias the pupil signal (see https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29330763/).
My recommendation would be to normalize the pupil size by the dynamic pupil range (see https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34014746/) to make comparisons between groups. However, this requires you know the min and max pupil size during light and dark conditions, which you probably didn’t get.
It is really important to control for these things during the design phase. For instance, use a baseline that is the same luminance as the images being shown.
You can probably control for this by using baseline luminance as a covariate.

To get figure B, I subtracted from the curves the value at 500 ms (the lower values due to PLR). The baseline was calculated using the range -500 to 0. The stimulus was the image of a face, started at 0 and stayed on the screen until the end (2000). Something that puzzle me is that the PLR seems to start before zero?
